# Multiple default selected items in Listbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking into creating an Edit page for a Company object that has multiple categories (that are predefined in a list).  I have the list being sent through the ViewBag, and have the categories that the user selected in the Create page in an Array thanks to a ViewModel.

I can't figure out a way to have the ListBox prepopulate with the multiple values in my array.  I was playing around with jQuery and was able to get one of the values to be selected, but when I try more than one nothing shows up.  Any ideas?

```
@Html.ListBox("Category", new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "Text", "Value"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectListItem` object has a `Selected` property to indicate this.  So I guess it would come down to how you build the `SelectList`.  Currently you do this:

```
new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "Text", "Value")
```

Which works, but gives you no control over the individual `SelectListItem`s.  Instead of building a `SelectList`, you can build an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` [using the same method overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470200(v=vs.118).aspx).  Initially that might look like this:

```
ViewBag.Category.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = c.Text,
    Value = c.Value
});
```

At this point you have more control over the individual items.  Now it's just a matter of determining which ones should be selected.  How do you determine that?  Is it a property on the `Category` object?  Something like this?:

```
ViewBag.Category.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = c.Text,
    Value = c.Value,
    Selected = c.Selected
});
```

Or perhaps some other condition?:

```
ViewBag.Category.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = c.Text,
    Value = c.Value,
    Selected = c.SomeValue == SomeCondition
});
```

How you determine that is up to you, and ideally something you can logically add to the backing model being used here.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't thought of doing it like that.  As far as how I'm determining which ones should be selected, I have an array in the View with the values that should be selected.  I'm thinking something like @Html.ListBox("Category", new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Category, "Text", "Value", "Array values here" ) ).  Not sure if that'll work yet though.